# Is there a CSS does not contain selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given the following

```
 <span id="foo_repeater_bar_0"></span>
 <span id="foo_repeater_batz_1"></span>
```

I want a css selector that will empower me to select only the items that don't contain `foo_repeater` in the id.

I know how to use the inverse, `span[id*=foo_repeater]`, but this I need help with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:not()` to exclude `[id*=foo_repeater]`.

```css
span:not([id*=foo_repeater]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="foo_repeater_bar_0">One</span>
<span id="foo_repeater_batz_1">Two</span>
<span id="repeater_batz_1">Three</span>
```

Comment: saw that the answer works! with regular css.. Thanks. was using nokogiri (a ruby gem) when I ran into this problem, though, and I'm not sure pseudo-selectors like `:not` work the same way with nokogiri. darn.

Comment: got it working with nokogiri. it needed parenthesis: `span:not([id*=foo_repeater])`

Comment: more information about nokogiri can be found here http://www.nokogiri.org/ I am using it to screen scrape

Comment: @DavidWest - Great! I've never used it. Thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [:not pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```
span:not([id*=foo_repeater])
```